# How to calculate the Bayes Estimator (Predictor) for the following problem?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, bayesian, estimation, predictor

Given the error function:

$$ 
e(y,\hat{y}) = 
\begin{cases}
    2,& \text{if } y<\hat{y}-1\\
    0,& \text{if } |y-y|\leq 1\\
    1,& \text{if } y>\hat{y}+1\\
\end{cases}
$$

I need to compute the Bayes predictor $\hat{y}$ given that the posterior distribution of y given x is **uniform** in the interval [5,10].

Can someone just give me hints what i need to do? How do i include my error function to calculate the $\hat{y}? $

Edit 1:

I think I have made some progress, by looking at other examples.
To find the estimator $\hat{y}$ we need to minimize:

$$\hat{y}=argmin_{\hat{y}} \int{\int{e(y-\hat{y})p(x,y)}dxdy}$$

which is:

$$\hat{y}=argmin_{\hat{y}} \int{\int{e(y-\hat{y})p(y|x) dy } p(x)dx}$$

in that case since p(x) is always nonnegative I am trying to minimize only the inner part of the integral:

$$\hat{y}=argmin_{\hat{y}}{\int{e(y-\hat{y})p(y|x) dy }}$$

now considering my error function what i think i get is:

$$ 
\int{e(y-\hat{y})p(y|x) dy} = \int_{-\inf}^{\hat{y}-1} 2p(y|x)\mathrm{d}y+ \int_{\hat{y}+1}^{\inf} 1p(y|x)\mathrm{d}y
$$

How do I calculate this integral now?